# Convert value from JsonObject to BigDecimal

Tags: java, json, jsonreader

I'm a newbiew in java language.
I want to get a value from a `JsonObject` and convert it to `BigDecimal`. 
I have the following code:

```
JsonReader jsonReader;
try {
    jsonReader = Json.createReader(httpRequest.getReader());
} catch (IOException e) {
    return Response.serverError().entity("Problem reading json body").build();
}

JsonObject jsonObj = jsonReader.readObject();

Map<String, Object> paramMap = UtilMisc.toMap("productId", productId, "internalName",
        jsonObj.getString("internalName"), "productName", jsonObj.getString("productName"), "productTypeId",
        jsonObj.getString("productTypeId"), "login.username", username, "login.password", password,
        "description", jsonObj.getString("description"), "longDescription", jsonObj.getString("longDescription"),
           "productHeight", (BigDecimal)jsonObj.get("productHeight"));
```

What I want is to do something similar to `(BigDecimal)jsonObj.get("productHeight")`.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you do that ? provide the stack trace of your error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `jsonObj.get` is not a method, so surely that's the error.

Second, I don't think that casting any object to a `BigDecimal` is going to work like that.

---

Reading the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReader.html)...

Going down from `JsonReader` to `BigDecimal`

```
JsonReader 
   > JsonObject
       > JsonNumber
          > BigDecimal
```

You can do

```
jsonObj.getJsonNumber("productHeight").bigDecimalValue()
```

This assumes that `productHeight` is a numeric value, and not a string, though.

If it is a String, look at [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) constructors. Specifically the one that takes a String value.

```
new BigDecimal(jsonObj.getString("productHeight"))
```